# ASP.Net Web API Help Pages: Ignore certain properties

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to have the Help Page sample generator ignore certain properties of a particular type?

For example, we use the same DTO for object Request and Response messages, for both POST and PUT requests. When user is POSTing a model (creating a new record) they don't need to provide the ID field.

But once its created and we serialize the new record into the response body, the ID field is included and returned to the client.

So in the POST request sample, I don't want the ID field to be displayed because for post request it doesn't make sense.

But the POST response sample, I do want the ID field displayed...

I am aware that there is the `ApiExplorerSettings` attribute which can be applied to a Class or Method...but is there anything similar for a Property?

Something like this would be great:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreForRequestApi = true, IgnoreForResponseApi = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties omitted for brevity...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a similar option for a property. HelpPage uses formatter instances configured on the application to serialize the samples and as you can imagine the formatters must not have this knowledge within themselves.

Regarding workarounds:

a. You could explicitly set the raw sample for a particular action's requestsample via the *SetSampleRequest* extension of HttpRequestMessage. You should be able to see some examples about this in the file at *Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs*.

b. In the file *Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\HelpPageSampleGenerator.cs*, there is a method called *WriteSampleObjectUsingFormatter* which uses the application's formatter instances to write the samples. Here you would need to create **new** formatter instances having similar settings as your normal application has(so that they reflect the exact serialization/deserialization semantics that your application would normally react to when actual requests are made) and then try to hide the properties which you want to. We want to create new instances because we do not want to disturb the normal functioning of the application.

Example: In case of Json, you could create a new Json formatter instance and provide a *ContractResolver* which can hide the properties. Check this link: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

In case of Xml, I am not sure how we can hide properties without using the IgnoreDataMember attribute and also being non-intrusive.

**Currently I would prefer option 'a' as its comparatively a simple workaround than 'b'.**

Answer (score 14):

Using the following annotation I've successfully hidden a property from the generation!

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Any method, or even whole controller you put this on, will be excluded from help.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET WEB API uses Json.NET for JSON and `DataContarctSerailizer` for XML formatting so if you add `[JsonIgnore]` annotations over properties that you do not want included in your serialization should work just fine.

Comment: I think what JTech is looking for is to only hide the property in the "Help Page" like ApiExplorerSettings can do for methods. [JsonIgnore] would however change the data that is passed to the user.

Comment: That works for me, I am not passing the property to user anyway.